# HackerRank dynamic array c# Runtime Error

Tags: c#, data-structures

I'm trying [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dynamic-array) HackerRank problem which deals with dynamic array in C#.

The following code is what I've tried:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
class Solution {
    static void Main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution */
        string[] arr_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            long[] arr = Array.ConvertAll(arr_temp,long.Parse);
            long N = arr[0];
            long[] S = new long[]{0,0,0};
            long Q = arr[1];
            long lastAnswer = 0;
            List<long>[] list=new List<long>[100];
            for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
            {
                list[i] = new List<long>();
            }
            for(int i=0;i<Q;i++)
            {
                string[] qry_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                int[] qry = Array.ConvertAll(qry_temp,Int32.Parse);
                if(qry[0]==1)
                {
                    list[(qry[1] ^ lastAnswer)%N].Add(qry[2]);
                }
                else
                {                    
                    lastAnswer =  list[(qry[1] ^ lastAnswer)%N][qry[2]%(list[(qry[1] ^ lastAnswer)%N].Count)];
                    Console.WriteLine(lastAnswer);
                }

            }

    }
}
```

The above code works fine for small test cases, but for larger valued test cases its displaying run time error.
The test cases for which it fails :
1000 1000
1 910205855 303787404
1 710990379 16287945
.
.
. so on

**How exactly can the code be improved for larger values and make it work and what property of data structure am I not understanding or missing.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First If N is larger the a 100 this will brake

```
List<long>[] list=new List<long>[100]//<Problem;
            for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
            {
                list[i] = new List<long>();
            }

List<long>[] list=new List<long>[N]//<Fix;
                for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
                {
                    list[i] = new List<long>();
                }
```

Second since `% list[(qry[1] ^ lastAnswer) % N].Count` can be a zero you will get an exception if the input is not right. 
This algorithm seams to be a waste of time. Note when ever you read the name Hacker and programing 90% is a bad way to learn programing.

Comment: Thanks Filip Cordas, that worked. I agree the question sucked away lot of time leading nowhere when u see what u learn. I would appreciate any other question , algorithm or website which leads us in a constructive learning of algorithm and data structures.